# Extent Report with TestNG is generated with broken UI

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, extentreports

I am new to selenium and TestNG, and I am trying to generate Extent report locally using Java.
The report is already generated successfully but in a broken UI as static HTML without CSS and I am not sure what is the reason for that .
Any help with that will be deeply appreciated .

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2NoP.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.